# immutable.js - replace node in complex and nested object

Tags: javascript, json, immutable.js

I want to update/replace fragment of my JSON object with other part by using immutable.js.

Look at the example below. We can see some more complex and nested object. In place of node with `"id": "F"` I want to replace/update with some other edited node.

According to [docs](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) I need to somehow get the `keyPath` as array and pass it to `setIn(keyPath: Array<any>, value: any): Map<K, V>` function.

So I need somehow find F keypath: [ 'children', 2, 'children', 0, 'children', 0 ] (is that correct?).

This is simplified example. In my case my keypath have much more complex hierarchy. How to do that by immutable.js or plain JS? Is this approach correct? Is it some more elegant solution to achive the same behaviour (perfectly using immutable.js functions if possible)?

Best regards,

Rafal

**Example:**

```
{ 
    "id": "A",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "B",
            "children": [

            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "C",
            "children": [

            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "D",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "E",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "F", // THIS NODE WILL BE UPDATED
                            "children": [

                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "G",
                    "children": [

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a way of efficiently determining the `keyPath` of the node you wish to update, then `.setIn()` is a straightforward solution that will get the job done.

There are, however, other ways to approach this, but they do depend on the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Given your example, if the `id` property is truly unique and you know what you are looking for (e.g. `"id": "F"` somewhere in the tree), then you could go with `.updateIn()` and create a predicate functions that searches for the specified node and updates it. Implement DFS or BFS, depending on your specs. If you are dealing with List structures, then `.find()` and `.findIndex()` could also be very valuable tools in composition.

There is another thing you might want to consider - flattening your data. It is not a favorite, but it can get the job done and it can also be a lot easier to work with for lots of UI stuff.

In the example of your graph, flatten it to a `List` of Maps and have every item keep a reference of the uuids of their children and/or parents. This way you can just traverse the List and find the element that needs to be updated based on a simple predicate.

Comment: Thanks. After your answer I decided to write my own recursive function which returns an array as keyPath. Now I can use immutable.js functions like setIn, updateIn etc. quite easily. However I still wonder how I could use immutable.js functions like .find(), findIndex() or fattening data to achive the same result. I wonder what of these methods has the best performance.